# web page redirect javascript

Tags: javascript, href

I dynamically create a link to a. 'mywebsite' is a variable. Everything works but the mywebsite page replaces that of the code. I want to open mywebsite in another page.
May I have a help to solve the problem ?

```
var mylink = document.createElement("a");
        var textForButton = document.createTextNode("More details");
        mylink.appendChild(textForButton);    
        mylink.setAttribute("href", mywebsite);
        document.body.appendChild(mylink);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the linke **target** as this:

```
mylink.setAttribute("target", '_blank');
```

Your code my be something like this

```
    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            let mywebsite = "http://www.google.com";
            var mylink = document.createElement("a");
            var textForButton = document.createTextNode("More details");
            mylink.appendChild(textForButton);
            mylink.setAttribute("href", mywebsite);

            mylink.setAttribute("target", '_blank');

            document.body.appendChild(mylink);
        };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `target=_blank` attribute to do this.

```
mylink.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
```

So that once you click on the link that you have generated it opens in new tab.